# Is there a way to pause SKActions?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, game-engine, sprite-kit

I'd like to create a pause menu but I don't know the simplest way to do this...
I think a simple way would be to pause all my SKActions, but I couldn't find any method in the reference.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13):

Documentation says that parent `SKView` object has a paused `property`. Set it to `YES` to pause the scene.

> **Paused**
>
> A `Boolean` value that indicates whether the view’s scene animations are
>   paused.
>
> @property(getter=isPaused, nonatomic) BOOL paused
>
> **Discussion** If the
>   value is YES, then the scene’s content is fixed on screen. No actions
>   are executed and no physics simulation is performed."

```
//the parent SKView
spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;

//pause button
-(IBAction)goPauseButton {
    if(!spriteView.paused){
        spriteView.paused = YES;
    }else{
        spriteView.paused = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) Your are right. All the animations and actions stop. But if i set the paused property back to no, the sprite move on where they would be if the view would have never get paused. Any idea why? :)

Comment: The pausing works fine for me, can you post your code showing how and where you call it?

Comment: I know what the problem of my code is... I use the current time from the update: method and the current time does logically not stop. So I have to fix that.

Comment: Do you have any Idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I fixed it ;) It was a problem of my code.

Answer (score 10):

You can also pause all the SKActions by setting the speed of the scene to zero-- this means that all the actions will stop, and you do not need to worry about them moving to where they would not have been if you did not pause

```
self.speed = 0;
```

easy as that